# WPF lambda expressions issue

Tags: c#, wpf, lambda

i have listbox view list of screen category from table ScreenCategory :
[image]

in edit mood, i have itemID (yellow),and i want to get collection of screen category
that assign to the selected item,

How can i do that using lambda expressions ?

i can get ObservableCollection from "ItemInScreenCategory"

```
IQueryable<ItemsInScreenCategory> query = _context.ItemsInScreenCategory
                                          .Where(s => s.ItemId == _item.ItemID);
_ocItemsInScreenCategory = new ObservableCollection<ItemsInScreenCategory>(query);
```

but how can i get ObservableCollection from "ScreenCategory" to used as itemSource for listBox.

hope this clear, and waiting for helping me ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            IQueryable<ItemsInScreenCategory> query = _context.ItemsInScreenCategory
.Where(s => s.ItemId == _item.ItemID)
.Select(s=>s.ScreenCategory)
```

`_context.Items.Select(i=>i.ScreenCategory)` should also work.

You get the ScreenCategories with that query and should build an `ObservableCollection` with the data